# Custom service that connect with Dynamic CRM SDK - Security permission issue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

Error : System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

When i host my wcf service (service inside Asp.net web application) in Local IIS Server, it is working fine. But when i hosted it in hostgator.com, it gives above error.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: hostgator probably runs your code in partial trust (Sandbox) so yo won't be able to deploy that.